# How to pass custom LambdaExpression using c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-expressions

I have a extension method to convert the class as datatable, in this extension method parameter I can specify the properties of class that I don't want to be add in datatable while conversion.

This is how I am calling the extension method.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        CancelMaintenance  cm = new CancelMaintenance ();
        cm.UserID = 1;
        cm.CancelReasonCodeID = 2;
        cm.CancelRefund = "C";          
        cm.Description = "test";
        cm.ReasonCode = "TestCode";

        DataTable dt = cm.ConvertToDataTable2(x => x.Test1, x => x.Test2);

    }
}
```

The extension method that I am calling here is like this

```
cm.ConvertToDataTable2(x => x.Test1, x => x.Test2);
```

I want to call like this

```
cm.ConvertToDataTable2(x => x.Test1, x.Test2);
```

So how do I change my extension method `Expression` type parameter to accept the properties like I am expecting.

**Extension Method**

```
public static class MyExt{
    public static DataTable ConvertToDataTable<T>(this T instance, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] proprtiesToSkip) where T : EntityBase
    {
        //Sample code ...
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        return dataTable;
    }
}
```

**Sample Class**

```
public class EntityBase
{
   public int UserID{ get; set; }
}

public class CancelMaintenance : EntityBase
{
    public int CancelReasonCodeID { get; set; }
    public string ReasonCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CancelRefund { get; set; }
    public string Test1 { get; set; }
    public string Test2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What would you expect a method call of `cm.ConvertToDataTable2(x => x.Test1, x.Test2);` to do? For *exactly* that syntax, that will not be valid unless you have a field (not local variable) called `x` in scope, at which point it would use that field for `x.Test2`, which probably isn't what you want. Perhaps you want `cm.ConvertToDataTable2(x => new { x.Test1, x.Test2 }`)?

Comment: Do you really need Expressions and not just Funcs? Also, it would seem much safer to reverse your code to only pass in the columns you actually want

Comment: @DavidG my only concern to provide an easy way to developers to pass the properties of class that they don't want in datatable. can you provide me the the sample code how to use only Funcs?

Comment: @DaisyShipton, yes this will also work 'cm.ConvertToDataTable2(x => new { x.Test1, x.Test2 }', is there any other way by using I can also remove the new keyword as well?

Comment: No, there isn't. That still looks pretty simple to me.

Comment: Thanks @DaisyShipton, I need to add one more parameter in extension method where user can specify the properties that he want to rename  while adding column in datatable, for example if property name is x.ReasonCode then it should add column name as "Code" in datatable. can you please explain how I can create this expression?

Comment: @NeerajKumarGupta: Sounds like you'd just want `x => new { x.Test1, x.Test2, Code = x.ReasonCode }`. Note that this would be a *single* expression tree parameter.

Comment: No @DaisyShipton I want to add 1 brand new parameter in extension method that should pass information like this x => new { {x.ReasonCode, "Code"} , {x.CancelRefund,"Refund"} } . This information is to change the "ReasonCode" property name in datatable as column name "Code"  and "CancelRefund" property as "Refund".

Comment: @NeerajKumarGupta: That sounds like a very longwinded way of renaming things given that anonymous types already have that ability with the syntax that I showed you. This is a long way from your original question though.

Comment: @NeerajKumarGupta You keep trying to create syntax. You have to use syntax C# supports, you can't create new syntax just because you want to. What do you expect `{ { a, b }, { c, d } }` to represent?

Comment: @NetMage, As I mentioned in my previous comment I want to add the functionality in my extension method, while adding property as data column in datatable! developer can specify the column name as well if he don't want same property name as column name, here  this code represents x => new { {x.ReasonCode, "Code"} , {x.CancelRefund,"Refund"} }  'ReasonCode' which is property name will be added as column name "Code" and other property "CancelRefund will be added as "Refund".

Comment: @NetMage the syntax that you are saying not supported like this { { a, b }, { c, d } } this is supported by the c# by using Dictionary.  Check this  "Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "A", "x" }, { "Y", "s" } };" in same way I supposed to take the input in my method.

Comment: Somehow `new Dictionary<string, string> { { "a", "b" }, { "c", "d" } }` doesn't seem like a good way to pass parameters. At that point a `string[]` would seem to be more concise as `new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" }`.